# Contact mobile number not shown in Messages

Tags: messages, contacts

When I type a Contact’s name in Messages in iPhone, the mobile number isn't listed but email address is. I have to tap the `+` button and find it in my Contact list.

What is causing this issue? How do I get it shown the mobile number(s)?